# How to count the number of rows based on another column type in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to count the number of rows based on another column type in SQL?

Database:

```
Department | Resource Type | People
===================================
HR         | manager       | john
           | staff         | jason
           | staff         | smith
IT         | manager       | wendy
           | staff         | emma
           | staff         | jay
           | staff         | cody
HR2        | manager       | john
           | staff         | terry
           | staff         | mike
           | staff         | fry
```

Expected output:

```
john, 5 employees
wendy, 3 employees
```

Thank you

Comment: In your data, what column value(s) establish the relationship between the manager and the staff employees?  I don't see any.  Is the `department` column really `null` for staff employees?

Comment: There are missing values in the Department column.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

It's actualy pretty easy to complete using a junction. This also takes care of a staff working for a manager in 2 different departments, and a department having multiple managers.

```
SELECT t1.People as ManagerName, 
    count(distinct t2.People) 
FROM @Staff t1 
LEFT JOIN @Staff t2 ON t2.Department = t1.department 
    AND t2.ResourceType = 'staff' WHERE t1.ResourceType = 'manager'
GROUP BY t1.People
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers, I also have to assume that all rows will have a value in the `Department` column.  Otherwise, there is no way to do what you are asking.

Also, your sample data seems to imply that every department only has a single manager.  So I'll make that assumption as well.

A simple query to do this would be this:

```
select mgr.people || ', ' ||
       count(staff.people) || ' employees' -- the string concatenation on these lines may vary depending on your database.
  from TableName mgr
  left join TableName staff
    on staff.Department = mgr.Department
   and staff.ResourceType = 'staff'
 where mgr.ResourceType = 'manager'
 group by mgr.people
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data sample, try:

```
SELECT S.Department,
       (SELECT TOP 1 SUB.People FROM dbo.Staff SUB
        WHERE SUB.Department = S.Department 
        AND SUB.ResourceType = 'manager') as Manager,
       COUNT(*) as Employees FROM dbo.Staff S
   WHERE S.ResourceType = 'staff'
   GROUP BY S.Department
```

I've made an assumption here that `Department` will contain a value for every record rather than just for managers and there is at least one manager per department.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e949/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating 2 temporary tables :

```
select People, sum(quantity) from(
select [ResourceType], People,quantity
from tablename
right join
(
select Count(Department) quantity, Department
from tablename
group by [ResourceType], Department
having [ResourceType] = 'staff') tmp1 on tablename.Department = tmp1.Department
where [ResourceType] = 'Manager'
) tmp2 
group by People
```